# React setstate not updating in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In functional component i am having onchange function where i am updating state but state is not updating immediately, means first if i enter first character it is reflecting when i enter second character, How can i update it immediately.

```
 const [customstartdate, setCustomstartdate] = useState();
  const [customenddate, setCustomenddate] = useState();
<Input
                      className={`form-control-digits not-empty`}
                      onChange={customHandler}
                      type="date"
                      id="meeting-time"
                      name="start_date"
                    />

const customHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "start_date") {
      setCustomstartdate(e.target.value);
    }
    if (e.target.name === "end_date") {
      setCustomenddate(e.target.value);
    }
    //having some functionality here
  };
```

Comment: Setting state happens in batches, and the state variable will not be updated until a subsequent re-render. If you need the "new" value for subsequent code, keep it in a new variable.

Comment: @crashmstr can you provide an answer for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setName(name)
}, [name])
```

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you add this in addition to the customHandler, or as a replacement of customHandler? Or maybe you put it inside the customHandler?

Comment: used it as a replacement of customHandler

Answer (score -2):

**Please search on google how to use react hooks,**

when you use `onChange` he can't run your function directly,
you need to write a callback that's run your function,

please follow my example and read more about react

```
const [name,setName] = useState("");
<div>
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" onChange={(eve)=>setName(eve.target.value)}/>
</div>
```

following this example, you can see that I'm using a callback function to be able to use the useState

Comment: `onChange={customHandler}` is perfectly fine. It is a function and it gets called when a change triggers it (no difference from having an in-line function or arrow function).